# Combine elements of a list with all possible separators

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following requirement.

I have a list which say has 3 elements `[X,Y,2]`

What I would like to do is to generate strings with a separator (say "-") between (or not) each element. The order of the elements in the array should be preserved.

So the output would be:

```
'XY2'
'X-Y-2'
'X-Y2'
'XY-2'
```

is there an elegant way to this in python?

Comment: Do you mean with and without the separator? Also, those are not really combinations but just putting the separator into all possible positions.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. The order of elements should be preserved. I will make the change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for c in itertools.product(' -', repeat=2): print ('X%sY%s2' % c).replace(' ', '')
XY2
XY-2
X-Y2
X-Y-2
```

Or, with the elements coming from a python list:

```
import itertools
a = ['X', 'Y', 2]
for c in itertools.product(' -', repeat=2):
    print ('%s%s%s%s%s' % (a[0],c[0],a[1],c[1],a[2])).replace(' ', '')
```

Or, in a slightly different style:

```
import itertools
a = ['X', 'Y', '2']
for c in itertools.product(' -', repeat=2):
    print ( '%s'.join(a) % c ).replace(' ', '')
```

To capture the output to a list:

```
import itertools
a = ['X', 'Y', '2']
output = []
for c in itertools.product(' -', repeat=len(a)-1):
   output.append( ('%s'.join(a) % c).replace(' ', '') )
print 'output=', output
```

Comment: Nice, but where is the list? :)

Comment: @RaulGuiu OK, I have added two forms with a list as the source.  Let me know if they are what you are looking for.

Comment: This is great. Thanks @John1024 . To add the results to another list. One could just modify as: a=[X,Y,2] b=[] for c in itertools.product(' -', repeat=len(a)-1): b.append(str("%s".join(a) % c).replace(' ',''))

Comment: @suzee Good idea.  I added that form to the answer also.

Answer (score 2):

A little more generalized but works for any number of separators and hopefully is easy to understand at each step:

```
import itertools
a = ['X', 'Y', '2']
all_separators = ['', '-', '+']

results = []
# this product puts all separators in all positions for len-1 (spaces between each element)
for this_separators in itertools.product(all_separators, repeat=len(a)-1):
    this_result = []
    for pair in itertools.izip_longest(a, this_separators, fillvalue=''):
        for element in pair:
            this_result.append(element)
    # if you want it, here it is as a comprehension
    # this_result = [element for pair
    #                in itertools.izip_longest(a, this_separators, fillvalue='')
    #                for element in pair]
    this_result_string = ''.join(this_result)  # check out join docs if it's new to you
    results.append(this_result_string)    

print results
>>> ['XY2', 'XY-2', 'XY+2', 'X-Y2', 'X-Y-2', 'X-Y+2', 'X+Y2', 'X+Y-2', 'X+Y+2']
```

These are the results for your case with just '' and '-' as separators:

```
>>> ['XY2', 'XY-2', 'X-Y2', 'X-Y-2']
```

If you want everything in one comprehension:

```
results = [''.join(element for pair
                   in itertools.izip_longest(a, this_separators, fillvalue='')
                   for element in pair)
           for this_separators in itertools.product(all_separators, repeat=len(a)-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a function in itertool in order to do that. But i always think it's fun and a good exercice to do this kind of things. So there is a solution with recursive generator :

```
def generate(liste):
    if len(liste) == 1:
        yield [liste]
    else:
        for i in generate(liste[1:]):
            yield [[liste[0]]]+i
            yield [ [liste[0]]+i[0] ] + i[1:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in generate (["X","Y","2"]):
        print "test : " + str(i)
        if len(i) == 1:
            print "".join(i[0])
        else:
            print reduce(
                lambda left, right : left + "".join(right),
                i,
            "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
from itertools import permutations

i =  ["X","Y","2"]
for result in permutations(i, 3):
    print "-".join(result)
```

Result:

```
X-Y-2
X-2-Y
Y-X-2
Y-2-X
2-X-Y
2-Y-X
```

Comment: Hi Monkut. Thanks. But the order of the elements in the list should be preserved. The output I am looking for is specified in the question.